# Swift: How to make a custom title view of the location that the pin was dropped at?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mapbox

So I am using Swift 4 and would like a pin to drop and then when the user touches the pin I would like it too come up with the text of that current location... When I run it the pin drops fine but after that I can not tap on the pin thus having no interaction at all with that marked point. I should note that I am using Mapbox.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Mapbox
import MapKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!
        let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
        @IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any) {
}
        @IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location = locations[0]

            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

            mapView.setCenter(center, zoomLevel: 10, animated: true)

            let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate

            annotation.title = "\(annotation.coordinate)"

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

}
```

Comment: You should check delegate methods of the mapView. Start with self.mapView.delegate = self. Normally you need to use didTapAtMarker method and implement what you want, it is probably similar with MapBox

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to handle tap on pin

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) 
{

     // Do something here
       print("Do Something here You Want)
}
```

Also see mapbox documentation https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#//api/name/mapView:tapOnCalloutForAnnotation

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding but I have a question where exactly would I implement ^ that into my code? Sorry I am a beginner at Swift...

Comment: place this method any where in your viewController Class  it will be automatically called when you tap on pin.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display the name of the location in a callout, you should have [`-mapView:annotationCanShowCallout:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.4/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:annotationCanShowCallout:) return true.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This allows the annotation to show a callout. You can also access the properties of that annotation (such as the title or subtitle) in that method. You may find this example helpful: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker/